# Rerun computation after throwing error

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I would like to combine the Error Monad and the IO Monad in Haskell. Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
type AskMonad = ErrorT String IO

askSomething :: AskMonad Direction
askSomething = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn "Choose an element from the list [1,2,3,4]"
  input <- liftIO getLine
  let entry = read input :: Int
  if entry `elem` [1,2,3,4]
  then return $ toEnum entry -- from Int to Direction
  else throwError "Invalid input!"

selectMove :: [Player] -> Board -> IO (Direction, Position)
selectMove players board = do
  direction <- runErrorT (askSomething) `catchError` --What to put here???
  -- Other IO stuff...
```

I would like to achieve the following behavior:

- if `askSomething` succeeds, get the `Direction`.
- if `askSomething` fails, `show` the error and run `askSomething` again.

However, I don't know what to put as the second argument of `catchError` in order to get this behavior. I think it should be of the following type signature: `Either String Direction -> AskMonad Direction`, but how can I access the computation that needs to be rerun (`askSomething` in this case).

Comment: you might be interested in this (opinionated) post about [error handling in haskell](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/commercial/content/exceptions-best-practices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as you have it now seems like it would be trying to catch exceptions not represented in the `ErrorT String` result. My thought is that you are actually looking to retry if `runErrorT` results in a `Left` value (an "expected" exception). In that case, something like this `retryForever` may work:

```
retryForever :: AskMonad a -> IO a
retryForever action =
  runErrorT action >>= either (\ex -> putStrLn ex >> retryForever action) return
```

which could be used like:

```
direction <- retryForever askSomething
```

P.S. I believe `ErrorT` was deprecated in favor of `ExceptT`, and that `ExceptT` is only more general so the transition should be trivial if you decide to switch.